# How to store additional values in an html table row and hide those values from display?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datatable, html-table, tablerow

I would like to store some business flags (like: isFavorite, isOnLive etc.) per an html table row that won't be visible to user.

In practice, I have a simple ADO.Net DataTable on my code-behind which is used as a data-source for a asp.Net GridView control.

This table contains some business flags on its 0th, 1st, 2nd columns.

I need to store those columns on the rendered HTML of the grid-view -so that I can reach them via JavaScript- but I do not want them to be visible.

Can you recommend me the best practice for such a case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign a style to the cells to hide them:

```
<tr>
  <td>Cell 1</td>
  <td>Cell 2</td>
  <td>Cell 3</td>
  <td class="hidden">Cell X</td>
</tr>
```

In your style sheet:

```
td.hidden {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set them in hidden input fields in a template column in your gridview. Just set the column to not visible.

You can find the hidden controls in javaScript and use its' values.

Comment: But isn't the visible set to false fields are not rendered in asp.net?

Comment: doh..yes you're right.

Then you can leave the column visible, but only to a width of 1px. The hidden input fields don't take up space.